# MS Excel If statement not working for shifts formula?

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

[image]

AE has formula :

```
=IF(
              AND([@[IST Time]]>=$AF$1,[@[IST Time]]<$AG$1),"First (6a-3:30p)",
              IF(AND([@[IST Time]]>=$AG$1,[@[IST Time]]<$AH$1),"Second (1:30p-11p)",
              "Third (10p-7:30a)"))
```

it should have shown Second instead of third , not sure what's wrong here.

Comment: Can you change their format to number and check if the numbers have the same relationship? IST Time might have a date value like 14.02.2019 16:02:08 and other dates might be something like 01.01.1900 06:00:00. In this scenario IST Time is bigger than all.

Comment: @MehmetYusufÇakmak , yes, in Number IST Time filed changes to "0.67". you are right. how to fix this ?

Comment: What are the number values of AF1, AG1, AH1?

Comment: Number values are showing as same for these 3 , 6:00:00 , 13:30:00 and 22:00:00

Comment: Try deleting values and type them again. I created the same thing in my computer and your formula is working.

Comment: @MehmetYusufÇakmak thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

There could be some issue with the cell reference `[@[IST Time]]`.  Try entering the following formula into cell `AE2`:

```
=IF(AND(AD2>=$AF$1,AD2<$AG$1), "First (6a-3:30p)",
     IF(AND(AD2>=$AG$1,AD2<$AH$1), "Second (1:30p-11p)", "Third (10p-7:30a)"))
```